# ListView Grouping?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, windows-store-apps, grouping

I have a Collection that I want to group. The grouping is like below.

Let's say I have a Person collection. Person has properties Name, Country, Gender.

What I wan to do in my ListView is group by country first, then group by gender, and the show the name of the person. For example, I want to see list of Names that is Male under USA, and another for other countries as well.

Also, when I add to this collection dynamically, ex. A new person, the grouping should still take effect, ie, he/she appears in the proper country / gender.

Lastly, I also need that the Grouping can be selected.. For example, I can click on the USA group, and then click on the 'Male' group and enter a new person there.

How do I achieve this?

Thank you!

Comment: Sorry if it looks like code request but it' not. I tried nesting listviews and collections but am wondering if there's an easier way using properties themselves and not collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MSDN has a full example on how to group your collection.  Then display it to a `LiewView` or `GridView`.

[How to group items in a list or grid (XAML)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh780627.aspx)

---

If you want to add an item after the grouping, then you will probably have to re-run the grouping code again -- or you can add it to the sub-collection with the key value that you're matching.

---

As for your "Grouping can be selected" that is entirely up to you.  Take the look at the example above, and modify the LINQ query to fit your needs.

Comment: Thanks, that is very helpful! When you say re-run the grouping code, like set the CollectionViewSource.Source again to the new collection? It doesn't work as a regular Two-Way binding would do?

Comment: I had the same prob, and got idea from the given link in the post. thanks buddy +1